# Static or dynamic array

Tags: vba, excel

I have following code:

```
Sub nummm()

    Dim num() As String

    For x = 2 To 1000
        c = 0
        ReDim Preserve num(UBound(Split(Cells(x, 7).Value, " ")) + 1)
        num = Split(Cells(x, 7).Value, " ")

        For Each b In num
            c = c + 1
            If c = UBound(num) + 1 Then GoTo vv:
        Next

vv:
    Next

End Sub
```

It's running fine if I remove line

```
   If c = UBound(num) + 1 Then GoTo vv:
```

but if it's not removed, I get run-time error: "This array is fixed or temporarily locked"
How can I make variable num dynamic?
thx for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how your `b` and other variables (except `num`) are declared but maybe this could help you:

```
Sub nummm()

    Dim num As Variant 'So you can directly assign the array from Split

    For x = 2 To 1000
        c = 0
        num = Split(Cells(x, 7).Value, " ")

        For Each b In num
            c = c + 1

            'Rather than "GoTo somewhere", "Exit For" will exit the current For loop
            If c = UBound(num) + 1 Then Exit For
        Next b

    Next x

End Sub
```